# Way to implement ADF user management

Tags: oracle-adf

I been doing some research lately for an application I must develop in the near future using Oracle ADF. I'm concerned on the user management, for my research I can see that the ADF security works pretty well and is "easily" configured on Jdeveloper. However, on the tutorials I have seen and papers I have read there is no clear answer to the way that users are managed.I have two question:

1. Is there an easy way to implement a front end for user management?
   so far all I have seen is handled on Jdeveloper and it works pretty
   well on development environment but I don't know how it would be on
   production.
2. How hard it would be to implemente a
   authentication/authorisation system with a DB table? no real
   documentation found so far.

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: If you deploy your adf application on a Weblogic server you can use it's default authenticator to manage users. More than than you can integrate it with multiple LDAP such as Active Directory, OID etc. I recommend you install weblogic 10.3.6 and give it a try, unless you are forced to use another app server or only database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF doesn't really care about user management. It however leverages authentication and authorization from WebLogic using OPSS.

You have to configure your external identity store in the security realm of your domain in WebLogic which will make the users from your identity store available in the ADF application but it doesn't provide features to manage those users. You will need to write this on your own.